# Google Fit API - International users sync issue

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm using the Google Fit API Rest

Here is the data I'm retrieving from Google Fit using the API:

```
2021-03-21    29989 Steps
2021-03-20    12 Steps
```

Here is the data the user exported from Google:

```
3/22/2021 16,480 Steps
3/21/2021 13,521 Steps
```

In both circumstances, the steps equal 30,001

The dates are clearly off by one day because of the time zone. The daily count is also off for the same reason, however, it added up to the same steps.

What general approach/strategy can I take to get the steps obtained from the API match those on Google Fit when I don't have a timezone?
My API currently loops through the database and syncs all user data, not distinguishing domestic vs international users.

Here is the code snippet used to get steps:

```
//***** Get steps       
      case DATATYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA:
        if ($dataStreamId == 'derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps') {
          $listDatasets = $dataSets->get("me", $dataStreamId, $startTime . '000000000' . '-' . $endTime . '000000000');
          if ($debug == 1) PrintR($listDatasets,"DATATYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA");
          $step_count = 0;
          foreach ($listDatasets as $dataSet) {
            if ($dataSet['startTimeNanos']) {
              $sec = $dataSet['startTimeNanos'] / 1000000000;
              $activity_date = date('Y-m-d', $sec);                  
              $dataSetValues = $dataSet['value'];                  
              if ($dataSetValues && is_array($dataSetValues)) {
                foreach ($dataSetValues as $dataSetValue) {
                  if(!isset($stepsArr[$studentencodedid][$activity_date])) $stepsArr[$studentencodedid][$activity_date] = 0;
                  $stepsArr[$studentencodedid][$activity_date] += $dataSetValue['intVal'];
                  $step_count += $dataSetValue['intVal'];
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      break;
      //***** End get steps
```

Comment: "Here is the data the user exported from Google:" how is that exported from Google? Is this from Takeout?

Comment: Also, how are you exporting the data? Is this with [`aggregate`](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate)? Could you post the "try it" link to show the parameters you're passing? (Construct your request on the right-hand panel)

Comment: @AndyTurner The user data was exported from Takeout. I added the snippet of code used to get the steps.  I hope this is the link you were asking for:
https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22dataSourceId%22%3A%22derived%3Acom.google.step_count.delta%3Acom.google.android.gms%3Aestimated_steps%22%7D     
Thanks, Andy

Comment: I don't think there's really much you can do here unless you know the user's time zone. Fit's REST API doesn't actually know the time zone, it just uses the start/end times you give it.